# Read french characters in text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

Hi can't read the french accent (like 'é') in a text file,
this is the piece of code I use to open and read the file...

```
FILE* file = fopen( [MyFileName UTF8String], "r, ccs=UTF-8");
if (file != 0)
{
    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL)
    {      
        NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: buffer];
        //Do many things.....
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

I can't see where is the problem, my file is correctly encoded in UTF8...

Thanks!

Comment: What happens? When it gets to the 'é' does it read "foobar" instead? Does it crash? Does it sound the beeper? Does it erase your file contents? ...

Comment: It read weird char like %#....

Comment: So, my guess is that the input is UTF-8 but the output isn't. How did you check the weird char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `fopen` and `fgets` you can read the content of file in a `NSString` by using `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` method directly.

```
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

The fgets function in c is ASCII only, you need to use the fgetws. This is the wide version of fgets for use with multibyte encodings.

Comment: Ok, but when I try to use the fgetws function I get an error during the compilation, do you have a example for this function. Thanks!

Comment: Did taskinoor's answer solve your problem, or would you still like an example? fgetws is rather unpleasant to work with.